# Automate npm and bower install with grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, bower, gruntjs

I have a node / angular project that uses npm for backend dependency management and bower for frontend dependency management. I'd like to use a grunt task to do both install commands. I haven't been able to figure out how to do it.

I made an attempt using `exec`, but it doesn't actually install anything.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.registerTask('install', 'install the backend and frontend dependencies', function() {
        // adapted from http://www.dzone.com/snippets/execute-unix-command-nodejs
        var exec = require('child_process').exec,
            sys  = require('sys');

        function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { console.log(stdout); sys.puts(stdout) }

        // assuming this command is run from the root of the repo
        exec('bower install', {cwd: './frontend'}, puts);
    });

};
```

When I `cd` into frontend, open up `node`, and run this code from the console, this works fine. What am I doing wrong in the grunt task?

(I also tried to use the bower and npm APIs, but couldn't make that work either.)

Comment: i'm in the same kind of configuration, and would like to know how you run ```npm install```? the same way? or is there an other way?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to tell grunt that you're using an async method (`.exec`) by calling the `this.async()` method, getting a callback, and calling that when exec is done.

This should work:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('install', 'install the backend and frontend dependencies', function() {
        var exec = require('child_process').exec;
        var cb = this.async();
        exec('bower install', {cwd: './frontend'}, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
            console.log(stdout);
            cb();
        });
    });
};
```

See [Why doesn't my asynchronous task complete?](http://gruntjs.com/frequently-asked-questions#why-doesn-t-my-asynchronous-task-complete)

Answer (score 134):

To install client side components during `npm install` at the same time than server side libs, you can add in your `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "bower" : ""
},
"scripts": {
    ...
    "postinstall" : "bower install"
}
```

I prefer to make the difference between install and test/build

Comment: most streamlined solution, and explicit separation of build and dev-setup concerns without adding additional grunt task aliases, or needing to add additional documentation to my project.  this is awesome, thank you!

Comment: most eggcellent ... squeaky clean

Comment: So simple! so so so simple.  This is by far the most elegant solution.  Thanks

Comment: Any reason you have bower as a dependency and not a devDependency?

Comment: @Patrick because I need to install browser dependencies in any environment. BTW I'm working on [Borrower](https://github.com/j-san/borrower)

Comment: While post-install hooks are usually an anti-pattern for node, I think that for this particular problem they are the perfect tool. +1

Comment: `"postinstall" : "bower install"` would just work in this case too, because `node_modules/.bin` is added to `PATH` env variable.

Comment: @FaridNouriNeshat I don't think that would be the case on a hosted CI build server

Comment: npm adds it when running the scripts so it works everywhere

Answer (score 7):

FYI, here is where i am for now.

You could also have taken the problem another way, i.e. let npm handle the execution of bower, and ultimately let grunt handle npm. See [Use bower with heroku](http://xseignard.github.com/2013/02/18/use-bower-with-heroku/).

```
grunt.registerTask('install', 'install the backend and frontend dependencies', function() {
    var async = require('async');
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    var done = this.async();

    var runCmd = function(item, callback) {
        process.stdout.write('running "' + item + '"...\n');
        var cmd = exec(item);
        cmd.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
            grunt.log.writeln(data);
        });
        cmd.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
            grunt.log.errorlns(data);
        });
        cmd.on('exit', function (code) {
            if (code !== 0) throw new Error(item + ' failed');
            grunt.log.writeln('done\n');
            callback();
        });
    };

    async.series({
        npm: function(callback){
            runCmd('npm install', callback);
        },
        bower: function(callback){
            runCmd('bower install', callback);  
        }
    },
    function(err, results) {
        if (err) done(false);
        done();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Grunt task that does just this job (as per Sindre's solution above):

https://github.com/ahutchings/grunt-install-dependencies

Answer (score 2):

Grunt task that does the bower install command : 
https://github.com/yatskevich/grunt-bower-task

also , you can use 
https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-bower-install

to auto inject your dependencies into the index.html file